# iOS: How to show nearby hospitals in skobbler maps?

Tags: ios, dictionary, skmaps, skobbler-maps

> I am creating a app in which it shows nearby hospitals,so am not able program it please if you know how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "code my app for free" what is this mean

Comment: It means that you need to show some effort. What have you tried so far ? What exactly does not work ? We can help you solve a specific problem, we _can't_ write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Thanks buddy i got it and thanks for your support and sorry for my weak English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SKNearbySearchSettings* searchObject = [SKNearbySearchSettings nearbySearchSettings];
        searchObject.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        searchObject.searchTerm=@""; //search for all POIs
        searchObject.radius = 5000;
        searchObject.searchMode=SKSearchHybrid;
        searchObject.searchResultSortType=SKProximitySort;
        searchObject.searchCategories = @[ @(SKPOICategoryHospital)];
        [[SKSearchService sharedInstance] setSearchResultsNumber:10000];
        [[SKSearchService sharedInstance]startNearbySearchWithSettings:searchObject];
```

Use this code for finding nearby hospitals.